# Add product programmatically magento 2: Unique constraint violation found

Tags: magento2, product, create-product

I added this script to add several products, but it appears this error:

> Unique constraint violation found

[image]

```
 $countallproduct = count($allproduct);
        for ($item = 1; $item < $countallproduct; $item++) {
            $product_data = $allproduct[$item];
            $objectManager =    \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
            $_product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
            $_product->setName($product_data->_source->name);
            $_product->setTypeId('simple');
            $_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
            $_product->setSku('test-SKU');
            $_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
            $_product->setVisibility(4);
            $_product->setPrice($product_data->_source->price);
            $_product->save();
        }

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting same sku for all products in loop, the sku needs to be unique for every product. Change test-SKU in following code to something dynamic such as index of the loop or something

```
 $_product->setSku('test-SKU'); //needs to be unique for each product
```

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, I changed it by this                 $_product->setSku('test-SKU'.$item); 
But it appears this error: URL key for specified store already exists.

Comment: @hanaayari This answer is right but not complete. You also need to set **UrlKey**. `$_product->setUrlKey('test-SKU' . $item)`

Comment: @hanaayari you should accept my answer if it helped you.